Исходит из сердца — это метафора?

Любовь исходит из сердца

Исходит из сердца — это что, метафора?
И как назвать правильно назвать приём, когда слово «сердце» является синонимом вместилища чувств?

Исторически не метафора. Сердце считалось источником чувств человека. Сердце - это не орган в данном случае, а середина человека, жизненный центр- сердце восходит к праиндоевропейскому корню "середина". Но если воспринимать по-современному сердце только как орган, то можно думать, что это метафора. То есть полагать сердце метафорой это скорее ошибка восприятия/знания о мире, у современного человека. Радость на сердце, сердце опечалено, злое сердце, сердце болит - везде сердце выступает как вместилище или источник чувств, так что думаю, не метафора и не синоним. Может быть олицетворение где-то.


Исходить из сердца — это устойчивое сочетание (мнение нейросети). Но с предупреждением: На основе источников, возможны неточности.

Я бы сказала, что это устойчивое словосочетание метафорического характера, так как мир мыслей и чувств соотносится с физическим миром.

В словаре:
ИСХОДИТЬ, -хожу, -ходишь; исходящий; нсв. 1. Устар. 
Выходить откуда-л. И. из подземелья. Из темноты исходит 
призрак. 2. от кого-чего или из чего. Выделяясь откуда- 
л., распространяться (**о звуках, запахах, тепле, дыме** 
и т.п.). От печки исходило тепло. Из столовой исходит 
запах рыбы. Звуки музыки исходили из соседнего дома. Из 
кустов исходил какой-то шорох. 


Предложения со словосочетанием «исходить из сердца»


Исходить может молитва, слова, замысел, чувство и т. д.
